# Finding last entry in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Here, got or gave are being entered with time. 
I am trying following code to find out which is the last entry: got or gave?

```
got(1).
gave(2).
got(3).
gave(4).
got(5).
gave(6).
got(7).

isLastGot():- 
    findall(G, Got(G), Lg),
    findall(A, Gave(A), La),
    Lgg is lastElement(Lg),
    Laa is lastElement(La),
    Lgg > Laa.

lastElement([H|T],A):-lastElement([T],A).
lastElement([A],A).
```

But it is not working:

```
?- isLastGot().
ERROR: functor/3: Domain error: `compound_non_zero_arity' expected, found `isLastGot()'
?- isLastGot.
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: isLastGot/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
?-
```

Where is the problem and how can it be corrected?

Edit: If I use following, I get the error on loading:

```
isLastGot:- 
    findall(G, Got(G), Lg),
    findall(A, Gave(A), La),
    Lgg is lastElement(Lg),
    Laa is lastElement(La),
    Lgg > Laa.
```

Error: ... /gotgave.pl:11:14: Syntax error: Operator expected
There are also many warnings of:   Clauses of got/1 are not together in the source-file 
(similar warnings for also for gave/1)

The file is not loading.

Even after putting all the got and all gave together, though the warnings and errors have gone away, the main runtime error is still persisting:

```
1 ?- isLastGot.
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: isLastGot/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
2 ?- isLastGot().
ERROR: functor/3: Domain error: `compound_non_zero_arity' expected, found `isLastGot()'
3 ?-
```

This is irrespective of whether I use isLastGot():- or isLastGot:- in declarations.

Comment: `isLastGot()` is invalid syntax in Prolog. Try `isLastGot`. In *both* places (the declaration and the call).

Comment: Even on correcting it to isLastGot:-  and then trying with isLastGot. I get the error: ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: isLastGot/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: There are numerous problems in the code. You show `Got(G)` and `Gave(A)` both capitalized, which is an error. These should be `got(G)` and `gave(A)`. I think I've mentioned this a couple of times, predicates in Prolog are not *functions*. They do not behave like functions. So `Lgg is lastElement(Lg)` does not make sense. It should be `lastElement(Lg, Lgg)`. You probably also received warnings about discontiguous predicates (alternating `got` and `gave`). In some Prologs, discontiguous facts/predicates will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cited in my comment several fundamental problems in the shown code. I'll spell them out more clearly here.

```
got(1).
gave(2).
got(3).
gave(4).
got(5).
gave(6).
got(7).
```

In the above section you should be seeing warnings about "discontiguous" predicates, or predicates "not together" (which is what "discontiguous" means). This is because you define `got/1` followed by `gave/1` then back to `got/1`. You have `got` and `gave` interspersed or interleaved. Many Prolog implementations will ignore the discontiguous definitions, so this is a problem. If you want to represent facts, they need to be contiguous:

```
got(1).
got(3).
got(5).
got(7).
gave(2).
gave(4).
gave(6).
```

Of course, I realize this works against the premise of the problem of figuring out which one came last. Using order of assertion as a means of creating a specific sequence of facts with only two different functors here is not a good approach. It would make more sense to express the sequence as a list, such as:     `[got(1), gave(2), got(3), gave(4), got(5), gave(6), got(7)]`. Then process the list.

```
isLastGot():-
```

As stated before, this is basic, invalid syntax. Prolog doesn't use empty parentheses to indicate no arguments. The correct form would be, `isLastGot :-`

```
    findall(G, Got(G), Lg),
    findall(A, Gave(A), La),
```

The above two calls have an error, probably typographical: `Got` and `Gave` are capitalized, but they should not be. They should be `got` and `gave`.

```
    Lgg is lastElement(Lg),
    Laa is lastElement(La),
```

The above two statements treat a Prolog *predicate* as if it were a *function*. Prolog *predicates* are not *functions* and cannot be called that way. You defined `lastElement/2` with two arguments, and the right way to call it would be:

```
    lastElement(Lg, Lgg),
    lastElement(La, Laa),
```

Finally:

```
lastElement([H|T],A):-lastElement([T],A).
lastElement([A],A).
```

The `lastElement([T], A)` call should be `lastElement(T, A)`. Since `T` is the tail of `[H|T]`, it is already a list and should not be expressed as `[T]`. That would be a list of just one element, which is itself a list. Your predicate will not work as written. Note also that Prolog already has `last/2` which does exactly this.

Comment: Perfect. After correction of all mistakes, it works. The answer is: ?- isLastGot.
true. ! Thanks.